# can frequently refreshed materialized views decrease overall server performance in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, server, database-performance, materialized-views

lets say i have a table that has frequently insert actions and i have 10 materialized views that are defined on that table. When i refresh MV in every 10 minutes MV's will select each time 50.000 rows from that table and then group and order by for each MV. I am saying this for 1 database.

and what about if i have 250 databases in that server that will make the same processes. Would this decrease server performance a lot? (i guess it would though!)...

Comment: Restating your question as "can frequently running large queries require lots of computing resources?" ... then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Is there any general approach to usage of MVs like a MV shouldnt be refreshed intervals for a time period less than one hour or a MV shouldnt be used for selecting/grouping/ordering large amount of rows(like 10k-100k etc)...because if you do so than you run out your server resources or smth like that i dont know.

Comment: Why have you decided that a materialized view is the best approach? Show us the test cases and performance measurements you have made and then people can advise you.

Comment: I would ask this at DBA, since it's not about programming.

Comment: hi @Richard Huxton . I am just trying to understand the possible costs of MVs in Postgresql. This is not about a particular project. Because when i get it right then i would do better database design approaches when the project needs frequent summarizing of data, or smth like that. That is why i need a very general approach to way of refreshing MVs like frequency of it or select data amount at a time, and group etc...

Comment: @cinfis - the cost of updating a materialized view is exactly what it would be do run the query and update a bunch of rows anywhere else. If it was substantially faster than updating a table then they'd use the same technique on tables, wouldn't they? The only way to decide performance questions is to measure.

Comment: @Richard Huxton yes i agree, actually i have read somewhere that it was advised not to use MVs refresh interval so small but it didnt mention about minumum interval time. so what i wanted to figure out was to learn this minumum interval for refreshing, regarding administrators' experience.(general approach)...if there is one for sure.